# Flutter allow iPhone upside down

Tags: ios, iphone, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a problem, all orientations are working. I tried everything, but I cannot get it to work.

The upside down orientation doesn't work. The content isn't changing.

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp
    ]);
```

Here is the problem, that only the normal orientation is working. Not upside down.

Did anyone find a solution for that?

Kind regards

Comment: Upside down isn't supposed to work on an iPhone.  I guess they don't want you to get confused when the phone rings and then you'd try to answer it upside down.   It does work on an iPad.  Try testing it with the built-in apps such as Maps.

Comment: But it is working with some apps, so I thought it would be able in flutter too. And there is a system option in Flutter, see above.

Comment: But the vaavud app, for example, uses it. And i want to rebuild this :-D

Comment: Hmmm.  It's quite complex.  From the Apple HIG: An app that runs only in landscape mode should be usable regardless of whether the user rotates the device left or right. An app that runs only in portrait mode should rotate its content 180 degrees when the user rotates the device 180 degrees—except on iPhone X, which doesn’t support upside-down portrait mode.

Comment: There is no iPhone X support because the newer iPhone have no headphone plug, and it's for a hardware device.

Comment: @vacawama thanks for the help, it was not flutter, my bad :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. It wasn't flutter, it was ios itself.

I had to add this:

```
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
```

to the Info.plist

Thanks